# Test OpenStreetMap with selenium webdriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, openstreetmap

How to Test OpenStreetMap with selenium webdriver (java)
for example : 
test buttons as routes, distance calculation and zoom.

i have try this code but any why, it impossible to click on the button iténaires.
tnks for your help !!

code :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/46.483/4.468"); 
Thread.sleep(3000);

WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='button']"));
button.click();
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: What are you trying to automate after opening the website ? This Xpath : //img[@class='button'] has 2 element and one of them is a button with find difference between two points as tool tip.

Comment: Can you please add the html

Comment: Hi, in this code i want juste click on button route to grab the destination; this is the  code**html**:  `<img class="button" src="/assets/directions-48d66684abd55f5458f7655691fdab6bf0c9ed50f6dfc090f37a9c885a22fc1b.png" alt="Directions">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automate OpenStreetMap with using Selenium WebDriver (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922936/how-to-automate-openstreetmap-with-using-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: Completely wrong approach: don't scrape the OSM website, as it will result in your IP being blocked. Instead you should probably install your own routing engine like OSRM or GraphHopper if you need directions. They all come with proper JSON / XML based APIs, which is the right way to consume those services.